# Lotto number random generator using javascript

Tags: javascript, printing, while-loop

I am very new to javascript. In my class, we wrote a code for a random number generator, but mine isn't working.  I was wondering if someone could look at it and tell me what I have done wrong.  I think my syntax is wrong on the loops, but can't be sure.

```js
function lottoGen() {
  var i = 0; //Variable for increment
  var d = 0; //Variable for decrement

  var arr2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; //6 array values. Begin at 0

  arr2[5] = Math.random(1, 26); //Choose random number for position 5 in array

  while (i <= 4) { //Perform loop while i <= 4
    arr2[i] = Math.random(1, 69);
    d = i;
    while (d !== 0 && d <= 4) {
      d--;
      if (arr2[i] === arr2[d]) {
        i--;
      }
      i++;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("lotto").innerHTML = arr2; //Print the array
}
```

```html
<p>Lottery Number Generator</p>
<form>
  <button onclick="lottoGen()">Generate</button>
  <p id="lotto"></p>
```

Comment: `Math.random` doesnt take any arguments and always returns a number from [0, 1[ (or [0, 1) in some areas)

Answer (score 3):

At the first iteration, `i` is 0 and therefore `d` is zero too, therefore this block:

```
while (d !== 0 && d <= 4) {
  d--;
  if (arr2[i] === arr2[d]) {
    i--;
  }
  i++;
 }
}
```

does not run as d *is* 0, therefore `i` doesn't get incremented, and you end up at an infinite loop. You actually want to always step through the array:

```
 while (i <= 4) { //Perform loop while i <= 4
  arr2[i] = Math.random(1, 69);
  d = i;
  while (d !== 0 && d <= 4) {
    d--;
    if (arr2[i] === arr2[d]) {
      i--;
    }
  }
  i++; // <<<
}
```

---

Additionally, `Math.random()` does not take any arguments and returns a number from 0 until 1, so to get an integer in a certain range you'd have to do use a small utility:

```
 const random = (min, max) => min + Math.floor((max - min) * Math.random());

console.log(random(1, 69));
```

---

PS: To be honest, your code is actually quite hard to understand, and the comments aren't really helpful. Instead of describing the code, try to describe what you're trying to achieve there:

```
 // Step through the array and fill it with random numbers
 while (i <= 4) { 
  arr2[i] = random(0, 69);
  d = i;
 // Check all positions to the left if the number is already taken
  while (d !== 0 && d <= 4) {
    d--;
    if (arr2[i] === arr2[d]) {
      // If thats the case, stay at this position and genrate a new number
      i--;
    }
  }
  i++;
}
```

---

How I would write that:

```
 function lottoGen() {
   const result = [];

  for(let count = 0; count < 6; count++) {
    let rand;
    do {
      rand = random(0, 69);
    } while(result.includes(random))
    result.push(rand);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  I will give this a try.